# Solve for $x:\log_x(\frac52-\frac1x)\gt\frac52-\frac1x$

Tags: logarithms

**Question:**

> Solve for $x:\log_x(\frac52-\frac1x)\gt\frac52-\frac1x$

**My approach:**

> I tried taking two cases when $x\gt1$ or when $0\lt x\lt1$.
> For the first case, I wrote $\frac52-\frac1x>x^{\frac52-\frac1x}$. But for this case, the book wrote $\frac52-\frac1x\gt x$. Why?
> Also, $\frac52-\frac1x\gt0\implies\frac52\gt\frac1x\implies x\gt\frac25$

> I tried making graph but couldn't conclude anything.

Answer (score 1):

I drew a graph and it looks like this:
[image: Desmos graph]

So as you can see, $0.4<x<0.546$ and $1<x<1.776$ seem to be the solutions. I am not sure if this can be done in an analytical way because I feel that there is SOME sort of $x^x$-like expression involved.

As for why the book wrote that, I feel that is because they are not trying to find a very accurate bound. For $x>1$, $\frac{1}{x}<1 \Rightarrow \frac{5}{2}-\frac{1}{x}>1$, meaning that $x^{\frac{5}{2}-\frac{1}{x}} > x$.